# Timeout on Gather verb (Twilio)

Tags: twilio-php

I am currently working on user interactive Twilio TwiLM.
Here is my TwiLM and when it times out, it just hung up the call.
I am not even sure if that is possible in Twilio, but can I keep it repeat to call the action (URL) over and over when it times out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather numDigits="1" timeout="10" action="twilio_handler.php">
        <Say voice="alice">Please press 1 to continue</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

If a `<Gather>` times out Twilio will look for the next TwiML verb in the document to execute, so if you want to repeat the prompt, what you could do is use the `<Redirect>` verb to redirect Twilio back to the same TwiML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/gather_hints.xml -->
<Response>
    <Gather action="/process_gather.php" method="GET">
        <Say>Enter something, or not</Say>
    </Gather>
    <Redirect method="GET">
        /gather_hints.xml
    </Redirect>
</Response>
```

You can find [this sample code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#hints) and more info on [`<Redirect>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/redirect) on our website.

Hope that helps.